# Vim search and replace based on surrounding text

Tags: regex, vim, replace

How do I replace `vector` with `std::vector` if and only if `vector` is not already preceded by `std::`? I could maybe come up with a convoluted way of doing it but I want something simple.

Comment: how about `%s/std::vector/std::replacement/g`?

Comment: @Fabricator Yeah that works, but I would prefer a one liner... and in general you don't know how to choose `replacement`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using negative lookbehind. This will replace `vector` with `std::vector` if and only if `vector` is not already preceded by `std::`

```
:%s/\v(std::)@<!vector/std::vector/g
```

Comment: Perfect. For future readers, `\v` makes all characters except numbers, letters and underscores special (don't need a backslash). And for more information use `:help pattern-overview`